# R shiny graph does not change when year from drop down selection is made

Tags: r, shiny

I had created a dropdown  of years from 2008 to 2018 using R shiny package .I have a plot which compares count of car models of US car makes and count of car models of car makes  data in my database ..I created the graph using plotly package and the database is connected . I want to get yearwise make model comparison..But when I selecting year from dropdown ,the graph has no change .No changes happening for each year selection.. The R code is given below

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(webshot)
dealerinventory1<-dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user='gbfb', 
                            password='gfhgfhh!', 
                            host='ffdhgfh', 
                            dbname='gdfhgfhn')

param_modelyear=c(2008:2018)
for ( i in modelyr){ 
  print(i)
}


modelyearquery=paste0(" (SELECT A.makename as AutonginMake,Case when B.makename is null Then A.makename
                      Else B.makename end As USMakename
                      ,A.AutonginModelcount,Case when B.USModelcount is null Then 0
                      Else B.USModelcount end as USModelcount
                      FROM (select count(*) as AutonginModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as C
                      group by makename) A Left JOIN (select count(*) as USModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.CarQuery where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as D
                      group by makename) B ON A.makename=B.makename
                      ORDER BY A.makename)
                      UNION
                      (SELECT  Case when A.makename is null Then B.makename
                      Else A.makename end As AutonginMake,B.makename as USMakename,Case when A.AutonginModelcount is null Then 0
                      Else A.AutonginModelcount end as AutonginModelcount,B.USModelcount
                      FROM (select count(*) as AutonginModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as C
                      group by makename) A Right JOIN (select count(*) as USModelcount,makename as makename from
                      (select distinct makename ,modelname  from dealer_inventory.CarQuery where modelyear=",param_modelyear," order by makename) as D
                      group by makename) B ON A.makename=B.makename
                      ORDER BY A.makename);")
makemodel1=dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,modelyearquery) 
plot5 <- plot_ly(makemodel1, x = ~AutonginMake, y = ~USModelcount, type = 'bar', name = 'USModelcount') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~AutonginModelcount, name = 'AutonginModelcount') %>%
  layout(
    title="Yearwise comparison of Models of each Makes in Autongin and US market",
    yaxis = list(title = 'modelcount'), 
    barmode = 'group')

k <- shinyUI(fluidPage(selectInput("my_dropdown","Choose Column", 
                                   param_modelyear),
                       plotlyOutput("plot")))

server5<- function(input,output){
  output$plot=renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(makemodel1, x = ~AutonginMake, y = ~USModelcount, type = 'bar', name = 'USModelcount') %>%
      add_trace(y = ~AutonginModelcount, name = 'AutonginModelcount') %>%
      layout(
        title="Yearwise comparison of Models of each Makes in Autongin and US market",
        yaxis = list(title = 'modelcount'), 
        barmode = 'group')
  })
}

shinyApp(k,server5)
```